# Font problem in nautilus with HiDPI

Tags: nautilus, fonts

I have an HiDPI screen on my laptop. Nautilus was great until now.

See how it is now: [image]

It can look ok for you but on fullscreen on my computer, the text is so small it's unreadable. I don't know how to fix that, the only thing I did is installing java8 (but I don't think it's related).

Any thought about ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A random action made it work (Rebooting my computer was not enough):

```
nautilus -q
```

No idea of what was the problem. It seems working now. I will set this anwser as fully solved after some hours of usage to test if this solution is definitive.

Comment: I made a simple script with just this line and added it to Autostart to run on login. Now nautilus (as well as icons on the desktop) is the correct size after login.
My best guess is that nautilus is started (in the background) so early in the login-process that it "escapes" the zooming.

Comment: According to [the man-pages](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nautilus) `nautilus -q` quits Nautilus, which probably runs in the background as part of the desktop environment.